# two keys one value pdo query result

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, key

my code is this

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM faculty";

    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
        foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
            echo $key."-".$value."<br/>";
        }
    }
```

it's fairly simple what i'm doing. My question is why am i getting the same value
two times, one with a key the name of the row in mysql (e.g "surname") and one the position of the array.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because your default fetch mode is set to

> PDO::FETCH_BOTH (integer)
>     Specifies that the fetch method shall return each row as an array indexed by both column name and number as returned in the corresponding result set, starting at column 0.

Try e.g.

```
$pdo->query($sql, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
```

instead.

see also: http://docs.php.net/pdo.constants

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast response and the solution!!! I forgot to say that i'm a beginner :(